# What is this aviation quote?

Tags: airliner, general-aviation, airplane

I remember hearing a quote about aviation that was something along the lines of “asking a pilot why he loves flight is like asking an artist (or a painter?).....”. For the life of me, I cannot remember what this quote is; however, once I saw or heard it, I fell in love with it. I wish I had wrote it down but I didn’t. I could have sworn that I saw this quote on the film “One Six Right” but after going through it multiple times, I have yet to see it written on the screen or heard a person on the film mention it. This question has been bugging me for a couple years and I cannot seem to find any help googling it. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This quote is from Barry Schiff, a [retired pilot from TWA](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/barry-schiff-retirement.pdf) and aviation consultant (but this is only the beginning of the story, I invite everybody to read the [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Schiff)):

[image]
<sup>Photo [stolen from AOPA](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2019/september/pilot/flight-of-passage)</sup>

---

Your recollection is accurate! This is indeed in [One Six Right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Six_Right).

[image]
<sup>Landing on 16R at Van Nuys, [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htqs9frOdo8&list=PL9Nd7WlaJy33UTE1AmSAYsrPP9Dd3x2xX)</sup>

He says that at the beginning (3:06) of the documentary. The video is not available online, but the first sentence of this quote is [often taken up](https://www.google.com/search?complete=0&biw=1600&bih=764&q=%22One%20Six%20Right%22%20%22like%20picasso%22), e.g. on page 39 of this [Midwest Flyer issue](https://midwestflyer.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MFM_FebMarch07.pdf).

The quote in its context:

> “Asking someone why they love to fly is almost like asking someone why
>   they like Picasso. The beauty is the fact that you can’t really
>   describe it, it’s something that you have to behold. Flying takes you
>   into another dimension, literally. We see, feel, and experience things
>   that people who don’t fly will never know.”
>
> Barry Schiff, Aviation Safety Expert / Pilot ([source](http://www.swaynemartin.com/student-pilot/review-one-six-right-the-romance-of-flying/))